# Multiparallel clone app clones not showing

Tags: file, clone, user-data, parallels, data-recovery

I have a clone app named 'Multiparallel' i created more than 500 accounts of a specific app and had 45 GB of user data. Suddenly, the app is not showing the clones apps of it. But when i checked on storage it stills contain 45 GB of userdata means the data is still there but app is not loading it. Is there anyway i can do to recover this data which still has in my storage but not loading up in app.

I tried restarting, moving to sd card (but option is not there to move) closing and opening again.